# Public IDictionary member of ViewModel class will not serialize via DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, datacontractserializer

I have a class that's my view model for a windows 8.1 universal application. I want to be able to serialize / deserialize this class as necessary. I have this working with the exception of the `IDictionary` public property. This property is being skipped. When I explicitly tell the `DataContractSerializer` to serialized by itself, it works as expected.

Why is it not being picked up by the `DataContractSerializer` when serializing the view model class? I have all the `KnowType` issues worked out as you'll see when I serialize the `DataDictionary` directly.

Here is the class in question

```
[KnownType( typeof( ViewModel ) )]
public class AViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
      public ViewModel()
      {
         DataDictionary = new Dictionary<double, IData>();
         SaveCommand = new RelayCommand( () => Save() );
         LoadCommand = new RelayCommand( () => Load() );
      }

      private string _firstName;
      public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; } set { Set( () => FirstName, ref _firstName, value ); } }

      private string _lastName;
      public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } set { Set( () => LastName, ref _lastName, value ); } }

      private IDictionary<double, IData> _dataDictionary;
      public IDictionary<double, IData> DataDictionary { get { return _dataDictionary; } private set { _dataDictionary = value; } }

      public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
      public ICommand LoadCommand { get; private set; }

      private async void Save()
      {
        //logic will go here, example in unit test below
      }
}
```

Here are the sub classes related to the `IData`

```
public interface IData
{
   string Type { get; set; }
}

[KnownType( typeof( BlueData ) )]
public class BlueData : IData
{
   public string String1 { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}

[KnownType( typeof( GreenData ) )]
public class GreenData : IData
{
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string String1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that I'm using to build the serialization

```
ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
model.FirstName = "First";
model.LastName = "Last";
model.DataDictionary.Add( 1.2, new BlueData { String1 = "TestBlueData", Type = "BlueData" } );

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer( typeof( ViewModel ) );
serializer.WriteObject( memoryStream, model );

memoryStream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

string xml;
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( memoryStream ) )
{
    xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here is the xml output I'm getting from the above code

```
<ViewModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationNamespace.ViewModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><FirstName>First</FirstName><LastName>Last</LastName></ViewModel>
```

When I call `DataContractSerializer` on `model.DataDictionary` directly, I get the following

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfdoubleanyType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><KeyValueOfdoubleanyType><Key>1.2</Key><Value i:type="a:BlueData" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationNamespace"><a:String1>TestBlueData</a:String1><a:Type>BlueData</a:Type></Value></KeyValueOfdoubleanyType></ArrayOfKeyValueOfdoubleanyType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the setter of your DataDictionary property from 'private' to 'public', then it should work as expected

Comment: I don't understand why. When I serialize the dictionary by itself it works as expected. Other reading I've done also says that the DataContractSerializer support serialization of IDictionary objects too.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I read the question too quickly(too much coffee). Yes it should work with DataContractSerializer. I believe there is a [CollectionDataContract] attribute you need.

Comment: That's used when building a custom ICollection object you want to be serialized sadly. I've been down that path too. I've also done the DataContract and DataMember attributes on all the classes above to no avail.

Comment: I have never run into this exact scenario, but you have me wondering now. I found this, maybe it will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx

Comment: Brian, we were looking in the wrong places - If you change the setter of your DataDictionary property from 'private' to 'public', then it should work as expected.

Comment: That's the ticket! If you want to update your answer I'll accept it!